# newhtml.html:14 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I'm working on a project and I  Got an error . I got the error "newhtml.html:14 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' " And Chrome mentions the problem in this line:
`user.name: $('#name').val();`  I don't know where is the error exactly ! I think everything should be good to go, but I don't understand why the : is somehow throwing this off.. any suggestions  ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
                  

              $(document).ready(function() {
                  var user={};
                $("#submit").click(function() {
                    user.name: $('#name').val();
                    user.email: $('#email').val();
                    user.password: $('#password').val();
                    user.confirmpassword: $('#confirmpassword').val();
                    var userObj = JSON.stringify(user);
        .ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "http://localhost:8080/WebApplication6/webresources/generic/all",
            data: userObj,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function() 
            {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function(error) 
            {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
});

    
    </script>


  
          
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
         

  
            <div class="col-lg-6 mt-5 mt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="100">
  
            
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Username" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                      <div class="validate"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                      <div class="validate"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                  <div class="validate"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                    <div class="validate"></div>
                  </div>
                <div class="text-center"><button name="submit" id="submit" >Sign In</button></div>
             
     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why line14 is  user.name: $('#name').val();
rather than user.name = $('#name').val();

Comment: you have some typos , to use JSON you need to use `$.parseJSON(' {"variable": "value"} ');` , also you need to call ajax by `$.ajax`

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two entirely distinct languages. I see no Java in you question.

Comment: edit tags and remove java and add JQuery and Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#submit").click(function() {
                    var user={name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val(), password: $('#password').val(), confirmpassword: $('#confirmpassword').val() };
                    var userObj = JSON.stringify(user);
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "http://localhost:8080/WebApplication6/webresources/generic/all",
            data: userObj,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function() 
            {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function(error) 
            {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



  
          
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
         

  
            <div class="col-lg-6 mt-5 mt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="100">
  
            
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Username" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                      <div class="validate"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                      <div class="validate"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                  <div class="validate"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                    <div class="validate"></div>
                  </div>
                <div class="text-center"><button name="submit" id="submit" >Sign In</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers given above work, just wanted to explain your misunderstanding.

If you're assigning properties at the time you define your JSON object, you can use `:` as you've done in your code. E.g.:

```
var user = {
   "property1": "value1",
   "property2": $('#something').val()
};
```

If you're assigning values to what are essentially variables outside of this object definition, you need to use `=`. E.g.:

```
var user = {};
user.property1 = "value1";
user.property2 = $('#something').val()
```

The two above blocks of code end up with the exactly same result, but you can see the difference in when to use `:` and when to use `=`.